# catcode in expl3 string

Tags: expl3, latex3, catcodes

(Forgot where I saw this but should be some official doc):

> A TEX string (and thus an expl3 string) is a series of characters which have category
> code 12 (“other”) with the exception of space characters which have category code 10
> (“space”).

Why is it catcode 12 "other" but not 11 "letter"? Does this mean even `A-Za-z` are all "other"s in a string? How does this interact with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the convention used by several tex primitives, which makes it natural to follow in expl3.  `\string`, `\jobname`, `\detokenize`, `\meaning`  all return token lists that are catcode 12 or 10.

`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` just switch the catcode of `@` between 11 and 12, are not directly related to this at all.

Comment: Then what is the exact difference between catcode 11 and 12? If it's OK to use 12 for letters, why must we switch between 11 and 12 for `@` but not let it stay at 12?

Comment: I mean, doesn't tex require every catcode in a control sequence to be 11?

Comment: @Cyker only when parsing a csname as `\abc`  if you use `\csname abc\endcsname` catcodes are not involved as long as the content expands to any sequence of character tokens of any catcode.

Comment: @Cyker when the catcode of @ is 11 then `\@empty` is a macro defined to be empty, if the catcode of `@` is 12 then `\@empty` is the command `\@` followed by the letters `empty`.

Comment: That's the point. TYVM